# Issue accessing member property of a class that is a property of another class

Tags: objective-c, properties, nsmutablearray, nsarray

Here's the first class:

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject {

NSMutableArray* array1;
NSArray* array2;

}

@property (nonatomic, assign)NSMutableArray* array1;
@property (nonatomic, assign)NSArray* array2;

-(id) initWithData:(NSString*)string1 andWords:(NSString*)string2;

@end

@implementation ClassA

@synthesize array1;
@synthesize array2;

-(id) initWithData:(NSString*)string1 andWords:(NSString*)string2
{
if ((self = [super init]))
{
    array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[string1 length]];
    for (int i=0; i < [array1 length]; i++)
        [array1 addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [string1 characterAtIndex:i]]];

    array2 = [string2 componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];

    NSLog(@"array1 = %@", array1);
    NSLog(@"array2 = %@", array2);
}
return self;
}

- (void) dealloc
{
[array1 release];
[array2 release];

[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Here's 2nd Class:

```
@interface ClassB : NSObject {

ClassA* classA;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign)ClassA* classA;
```

Im having issues gaining access to the properties of ClassA, that are stored in ClassB.

For instance, I want to do something like:

```
// print out the arrays stored in Class B 
NSLog(@"%@",[[classB classA] array1]);
NSLog(@"%@",[[classB classA] array2]);
```

array1 prints out okay, but array2 throws and EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.  I'm guessing because

```
array2 = [string2 componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
```

is not allocating properly.

Comment: So, what errors are you getting?

Comment: What kind of "issues" are you having? What is the output of your NSLog statements?

Comment: I get an "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error on that line.

Comment: Then you should provide details on how classB's classA property is set

Comment: Class B's classA property is set by first created an instance of ClassA and then using the setter method of ClassB, to set the created instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's much easier to let Apple handle the memory management for you: change your `array1` and `array2` properties from `assign` to `retain` and then use the following in your `init`:

```
NSMutableArray* newArray1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[string1 length]];
for (int i=0; i < [array1 length]; i++)
    [array1 addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [string1 characterAtIndex:i]]];
[self setArray1:newArray1];

[self setArray2:[string2 componentsSeparatedByString:@";"]];
```

This way, your `@synthesize`d setter methods will handle retaining the properties for you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that array2 is being autoreleased because you are creating it with one of NSString's convenience methods rather then explicitly allocating the array. Try retaining the results instead of just setting your iVar to the autoreleased string.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by first calling alloc:

```
array2 = [NSArray alloc];
array2 = [string2 componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
```

Comment: This is NOT a correct solution. Use my answer, and read Apple's guide on memory management before writing anything else!